# perl "DateTime" module print wrong time

Tags: perl

I am using [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/~drolsky/DateTime-0.78/lib/DateTime.pm) module. however it is providing wrong time. Please consider below code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Time::localtime;
my $now = ctime();
print $now."\n";

print "------------------------------\n";

use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now;
print $dt."\n";
```

And its output is:

```
Wed Dec 26 22:11:52 2012
------------------------------
2012-12-27T06:11:52
```

so, As you can see, the `DateTime` output is leading by 8 hours which is wrong. Here is the Linux `date` command output:

```
# date
Wed Dec 26 22:13:17 PST 2012
```

So, the `date` command output matches with that of `time::localtime` output.

could you help me understand where I am going wrong in using `DateTime` module.

-Thanks.

**UPDATE:**

from hte CPAN documentation:

```
DateTime->now( ... )

This class method is equivalent to calling from_epoch() with the value returned from Perl's time() function. Just as with the new() method, it accepts "time_zone" and "locale" parameters.

By default, the returned object will be in the UTC time zone.
```

So, It seems that the time returned is in UTC. However, the timezone I am in in PST. Probably thats why I see the different time.

Comment: I'm assuming that you are in the Pacific time zone?  You need to tell DateTime what time zone you're wanting.

Comment: yes, I just updated my post. It returns UTC time. Reading further to find out how to pass the timezone information. Thanks.

Comment: You have just learned your first lesson with timezones.  From henceforth, the first thing you will think when a time is not what you expected is to check the timezone.

Comment: These people "correcting" you are wrong. There is no reason a user should know the timezone that the machine is in.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I passed the zone info and it works perfectly now:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use strict;

use Time::localtime;
my $now = ctime();
print $now."\n";

print "------------------------------\n";

use DateTime;
my $dt = DateTime->now ( time_zone => 'America/Los_Angeles' );
print $dt."\n";
```

Output:

```
Wed Dec 26 22:28:44 2012
------------------------------
2012-12-26T22:28:44
```

For East Coast

```
my $dateF = DateTime->now( time_zone => 'America/New_York' )->ymd;
```

Answer (score 2):

There is no reason a user should know the time zone of the machine (which might be across the world), and even if they did, it's a bad idea to hard code that. The answer is

```
my $dt = DateTime->now(time_zone => 'local') # current time, local timezone
my $dt = DateTime->from_epoch(epoch=>time(), time_zone=>'local') # from timestamp
```

which will set it to the time zone of the machine.